# How do I find the distribution of given data?

Tags: python, r, scipy, statistics, wolfram-mathematica

In R-Language and Wolfram Mathematica you can apply method to  find the family of the distribution your data follows such as ''Poisson-geometric-Gamma  etc. and many many other distributions.
But in Python it's impossible to know the distribution the maximum thing you can in python just plot the histogram & after that you have to figure it out !! which is impossible thing .

My question is there any way to identify the distribution of my data in python by importing certain libraries? or by doing it manually "coding". Kindly help

Comment: As you typed in your question, this and similar questions with answers were recommended.

Comment: Yup. Its correct .